# Select specific dates and calculate values' pct_change in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each group `city` and `district` in the following dataframe, I want to use `price` values of `2019-03` as base values, calculating `2019-06` and `2019-12` months' `price` values percentage changes comparing to the values in `2019-03`.

```
   city district     date     price
0     a        c  2019-01        9.99
1     a        c  2019-02       10.66
2     a        c  2019-03       10.56
3     a        c  2019-04       10.06
4     a        c  2019-05       10.69
5     a        c  2019-06       10.77
6     a        c  2019-07       10.67
7     a        c  2019-08       10.51
8     a        c  2019-09       10.28
9     a        c  2019-10       10.05
10    a        c  2019-11        9.72
11    a        c  2019-12        9.98
12    b        d  2019-01        6.32
13    b        d  2019-02        6.32
14    b        d  2019-03        6.32
15    b        d  2019-04        6.32
16    b        d  2019-05        6.32
17    b        d  2019-06        6.00
18    b        d  2019-07        6.00
19    b        d  2019-08        6.00
20    b        d  2019-09        6.00
21    b        d  2019-10        6.00
22    b        d  2019-11        6.00
23    b        d  2019-12        5.65
```

How can I get expected result will like this? Thank you.

```
   city district     date  price       pct
0     a        c  2019-01   9.99       NaN
1     a        c  2019-02  10.66       NaN
2     a        c  2019-03  10.56       NaN
3     a        c  2019-04  10.06       NaN
4     a        c  2019-05  10.69       NaN
5     a        c  2019-06  10.77  0.019886
6     a        c  2019-07  10.67       NaN
7     a        c  2019-08  10.51       NaN
8     a        c  2019-09  10.28       NaN
9     a        c  2019-10  10.05       NaN
10    a        c  2019-11   9.72       NaN
11    a        c  2019-12   9.98 -0.054924
12    b        d  2019-01   6.32       NaN
13    b        d  2019-02   6.32       NaN
14    b        d  2019-03   6.32       NaN
15    b        d  2019-04   6.32       NaN
16    b        d  2019-05   6.32       NaN
17    b        d  2019-06   6.00 -0.050633
18    b        d  2019-07   6.00       NaN
19    b        d  2019-08   6.00       NaN
20    b        d  2019-09   6.00       NaN
21    b        d  2019-10   6.00       NaN
22    b        d  2019-11   6.00       NaN
23    b        d  2019-12   5.65 -0.106013
```

Just tried with `df['pct1'] = df.groupby(['city', 'district'])['price'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(5)); df['pct2'] = df.groupby(['city', 'district'])['price'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(11))`, clearly I didn't get I need.

Output from current code:

```
   city district     date  price      pct1      pct2
0     a        c  2019-01   9.99       NaN       NaN
1     a        c  2019-02  10.66       NaN       NaN
2     a        c  2019-03  10.56       NaN       NaN
3     a        c  2019-04  10.06       NaN       NaN
4     a        c  2019-05  10.69       NaN       NaN
5     a        c  2019-06  10.77  0.078078       NaN
6     a        c  2019-07  10.67  0.000938       NaN
7     a        c  2019-08  10.51 -0.004735       NaN
8     a        c  2019-09  10.28  0.021869       NaN
9     a        c  2019-10  10.05 -0.059869       NaN
10    a        c  2019-11   9.72 -0.097493       NaN
11    a        c  2019-12   9.98 -0.064667 -0.001001
12    b        d  2019-01   6.32       NaN       NaN
13    b        d  2019-02   6.32       NaN       NaN
14    b        d  2019-03   6.32       NaN       NaN
15    b        d  2019-04   6.32       NaN       NaN
16    b        d  2019-05   6.32       NaN       NaN
17    b        d  2019-06   6.00 -0.050633       NaN
18    b        d  2019-07   6.00 -0.050633       NaN
19    b        d  2019-08   6.00 -0.050633       NaN
20    b        d  2019-09   6.00 -0.050633       NaN
21    b        d  2019-10   6.00 -0.050633       NaN
22    b        d  2019-11   6.00  0.000000       NaN
23    b        d  2019-12   5.65 -0.058333 -0.106013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isin` without `groupby` and for division of first value use `transform`:

```
m = df["date"].isin(['2019-01', '2019-06', '2019-12'])
s = df[m].groupby(["city","district"])['price'].transform('first')

df.loc[m, 'pct1'] = df.loc[m, 'price'].div(s).sub(1)
print (df)
   city district     date  price      pct1
0     a        c  2019-01   9.99  0.000000
1     a        c  2019-02  10.66       NaN
2     a        c  2019-03  10.56       NaN
3     a        c  2019-04  10.06       NaN
4     a        c  2019-05  10.69       NaN
5     a        c  2019-06  10.77  0.078078
6     a        c  2019-07  10.67       NaN
7     a        c  2019-08  10.51       NaN
8     a        c  2019-09  10.28       NaN
9     a        c  2019-10  10.05       NaN
10    a        c  2019-11   9.72       NaN
11    a        c  2019-12   9.98 -0.001001
12    b        d  2019-01   6.32  0.000000
13    b        d  2019-02   6.32       NaN
14    b        d  2019-03   6.32       NaN
15    b        d  2019-04   6.32       NaN
16    b        d  2019-05   6.32       NaN
17    b        d  2019-06   6.00 -0.050633
18    b        d  2019-07   6.00       NaN
19    b        d  2019-08   6.00       NaN
20    b        d  2019-09   6.00       NaN
21    b        d  2019-10   6.00       NaN
22    b        d  2019-11   6.00       NaN
23    b        d  2019-12   5.65 -0.106013
```

Comment: Thank you as always. I'll test with my data, if there are some problems, i'll let you know.

Comment: Do you know what `x.iat[0]` means in the code below?

Comment: @ahbon - `x.iat[0]` means first value of group, in my code it is `first`

Comment: Ok why I get ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis with Henry Yik’s solution, any ideas?

Comment: @ahbon - first idea should be create default index by `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution.

Comment: The second groupby from his second solution.

Comment: @ahbon - hmmm, hard question. I guess it should be correct `mask = df.groupby(["city","district"])["date"]
               .apply(lambda x: x.isin(['2019-01', '2019-06', '2019-12']))` and then `df.loc[mask, "pct"] = df[mask].groupby(["city","district"])['price'].apply(lambda x: x/x.iat[0]-1)`

Comment: Great I’ll try and let u know.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate all percentages first and then set `nan` to non-required months:

```
df["pct"] = df.groupby(["city","district"])['price'].apply(lambda x: x/x.iat[0]-1)
df.loc[~df["date"].isin(['2019-06', '2019-12']),"pct"] = np.NaN

print (df)

   city district     date  price       pct
0     a        c  2019-01   9.99       NaN
1     a        c  2019-02  10.66       NaN
2     a        c  2019-03  10.56       NaN
3     a        c  2019-04  10.06       NaN
4     a        c  2019-05  10.69       NaN
5     a        c  2019-06  10.77  0.078078
6     a        c  2019-07  10.67       NaN
7     a        c  2019-08  10.51       NaN
8     a        c  2019-09  10.28       NaN
9     a        c  2019-10  10.05       NaN
10    a        c  2019-11   9.72       NaN
11    a        c  2019-12   9.98 -0.001001
12    b        d  2019-01   6.32       NaN
13    b        d  2019-02   6.32       NaN
14    b        d  2019-03   6.32       NaN
15    b        d  2019-04   6.32       NaN
16    b        d  2019-05   6.32       NaN
17    b        d  2019-06   6.00 -0.050633
18    b        d  2019-07   6.00       NaN
19    b        d  2019-08   6.00       NaN
20    b        d  2019-09   6.00       NaN
21    b        d  2019-10   6.00       NaN
22    b        d  2019-11   6.00       NaN
23    b        d  2019-12   5.65 -0.106013
```

Or create a mask with months 1,6,12, and then calculate the percentange:

```
df["pct"] = (df[df.groupby(["city","district"])["date"]
               .apply(lambda x: x.isin(['2019-01', '2019-06', '2019-12']))]
               .groupby(["city","district"])['price'].apply(lambda x: x/x.iat[0]-1))

print (df)

   city district     date  price       pct
0     a        c  2019-01   9.99  0.000000
1     a        c  2019-02  10.66       NaN
2     a        c  2019-03  10.56       NaN
3     a        c  2019-04  10.06       NaN
4     a        c  2019-05  10.69       NaN
5     a        c  2019-06  10.77  0.078078
6     a        c  2019-07  10.67       NaN
7     a        c  2019-08  10.51       NaN
8     a        c  2019-09  10.28       NaN
9     a        c  2019-10  10.05       NaN
10    a        c  2019-11   9.72       NaN
11    a        c  2019-12   9.98 -0.001001
12    b        d  2019-01   6.32  0.000000
13    b        d  2019-02   6.32       NaN
14    b        d  2019-03   6.32       NaN
15    b        d  2019-04   6.32       NaN
16    b        d  2019-05   6.32       NaN
17    b        d  2019-06   6.00 -0.050633
18    b        d  2019-07   6.00       NaN
19    b        d  2019-08   6.00       NaN
20    b        d  2019-09   6.00       NaN
21    b        d  2019-10   6.00       NaN
22    b        d  2019-11   6.00       NaN
23    b        d  2019-12   5.65 -0.106013
```

Comment: Thank you, instead of `endswith`, if I want use `isin(['2019-01', '2019-06', '2019-12'])`, how can I modify your code?

Comment: You can replace `str.endswith(...)` with `isin(...)` as edited above.

Comment: Sorry I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` with your second solution. Any ideas?